# startActivityForResult from ActivityGroup?

Tags: android, activitygroup

I can't seem to get ANY result when trying to start an activity from an activitygroup.  I've put an onactivityresult in the activity and activitygroup?  Specifically I'm trying to let the user choose a photo/video from the Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, but I never get anything back?  What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I call the code:

```
Intent pickMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   pickMedia.setType("video/*");
   startActivityForResult(pickMedia,12345);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Steven,
Could you please provide a little more clarity as to what you mean via code? Thanks!

Comment: Jon - it looks like Nagkeeran used my approach to solve his issue. He posted some sample code at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992142/android-wait-for-another-activity-result-it-didnt-work

Answer (score 41):

I've had a similar issue. I had an ActivityGroup managing sub-activities. One of the sub-activities called a similar external intent (external to my app). It never called the onActivityResult within the sub-activity that started it.

I finally figured out/remembered that the issue is because Android will only allow a nested layer of sub-activities...ie sub-activities can't nest sub-activitites. To solve this:

1. call `getParent().startActivityForResult()` from your sub-activity
2. your parent (the activitygroup) will be able to handle the `onActivityResult`. So I created a subclass of `ActivityGroup` and handled this `onActivityResult`.
3. You can re-route that result back to the sub-activity if you need to. Just get the current activity by `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()` . My sub-activities inherit from a custom activity so I added a `handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` in that subclass for the `ActivityGroup` to call.

Comment: i have same problem and i am not able to understand please can you explain it

Comment: @Steven Pena, Then how you have called getDecorView() for startActivityForResult to get replace view of ActivityGroup

Comment: +1 That worked! I followed steps 1 and 2. After that I maintained a static reference to my current activity and propagated the result back there - kind of a hack but worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Your Parent Activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)   {

        CHILD_ACTIVITY_NAME activity = (CHILD_ACTIVITY_NAME)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();

        activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);}}
```

So your childern activity's onActivityResult will run.