# stuck with getting camera pic when using the tab Activity

Tags: android

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 


            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(getParent(),TakePicture.class);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("image",thumbnail);
            OpenBeeActivityGroup opentActivity = (OpenBeeActivityGroup)getParent();         
            opentActivity.startChildActivity("TakePicture Activity",takePictureIntent);
```

Comment: putting on my mind-reading hat... nope, doesn't work :)

Comment: but why any reason from your side...

Comment: any any other way to accomplish the task...?

Comment: @kamal_tech_view : hello sir, can you help me to solve this little issue? I'm facing the same issue as yours but can't understand the given solutions here..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for I understand from your Question is,
This happen while using `ActivityGroup`. Since you are starting `Activity` for result inside a child `Activity`  (i.e `TakePicture.class`), and Android will only allow single nested layer of child `Activity`(ies) (means child `Activity` cannot nest another child `Activity`).
And you are probably handling the result in your child `Activity`(i.e `TakePicture.class`).

So the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4569579/593709) to your problem is to handle that result inside your parent `Activity` (`OpenBeeActivityGroup`)'s `onActivityResult()` and then send your result to the active `Activity`.
you will use something like this.
inside your child Activity start your `startActivityForResult()` from parent `Activity` like.

```
getParent().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,Global.CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

and inside your `onActivityResult()` of `ActivityGroup` (`OpenBeeActivityGroup`):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case Global.CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST: // global variable to indicate camera result
        Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
        activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If there is one more child class from where I would like to start camera intent then also I need to capture onActivityResult on the parent i.e OpenBeeActivityGroup ?

Comment: Yea if you are starting your child `Activity` using `getParent().startChildActivity("AnyString",intent);` then you will handle the result in `OpenBeeActivityGroup`

Comment: @Adil... hello sir, can you help me to solve this little issue?

Answer (score 0):

Along these lines, I have tried to start the camera using your code, and if you truly have it nested, then you cannot again call startActivityForResult.  What you need to do is extend ActivityGroup to handle starting a child activity for result.  I had to figure this out - HTH.

Comment: can u please elaborate your answer, how to do this? i have same issue in my app.

Comment: The first problem is are you using android 4 or not?  If you are using 4, you need to add it to fragmentmanager to start the camera activity.  If you are not, then the tabcontainer activity has to have a function that serves as a pass through.

Tab 1 = Y
Tab 2 = Z
Manager = X

So if you want to call the camera in Y, you need to use the start activity for result in X and then pass the result through back to Y

Comment: I just switched to 4.0 and it fixed all of my complicated code.  I love fragments now!