# issue with startActivityForResult in tab group in android

Tags: android, tabs, gallery

i have a 3 tabs in my app.One tab (`Pitchin`) requires replacing of the view, so i created a class that extends ActivityGroup.

i used to replace the view like this:

```
View view = PitchinTab.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
                 .startActivity("Items", new 
                  Intent(Pitchin.this, send.class)   
                 .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
                 .getDecorView();  
                  PitchinTab.group.replaceView(view);
```

What my problem is, i need to call built in gallery from `PitchIn` class, For this i have done like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setType("image/*");

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"SelectPicture"),SELECT_PICTURE);
```

And i am handling result in OnActivityResult like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);
                test.setImageURI(uri);
      }
    }
  }
```

Gallery is opening  but i cant get picture in my activity.i am unable to handle OnActivityResult,problem is due to i used ActivityGroup.

How to get result from gallery to Tab when using ActiviyGroup?

i find some links but i didnt get right solution yet, Please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: could refer to this [my SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677466/stuck-with-getting-camera-pic-when-using-the-tab-activity/6679665#6679665)

Comment: @adil thank you for reply, as per your answer can i set my image in onActivityResult?

Comment: Yea, you have to call your current `Activity` 's `onActivityResult()` inside your `ActivityGroup` 's `onActivityResult()`

Comment: ok i need to create onActvityResult in ActivityGroup, right?

Comment: Yea, and from there call the current `Activity`'s `onActivityResult()`

Comment: one more doubt plz,  activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); In this line showing error

Comment: @Abhi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2880/discussion-between-adil-soomro-and-abhi)

Comment: @adil it is working, can we change the view in Activity's onActivityResult()?

Comment: come to chat, let us disscuss

Comment: @Abhi... I'm facing the same issue as yours... Can u please help me out to solve this problem?