# onActivityResult doesn't work for Camera -Tab ActivityGrup

Tags: android

I want to capture image & save it to SD card. Now its working fine. 
My problem is 1) after capture  `OK  and Cancel` button are avialble.When I click Ok only it need to save the image into SD card.

2) It doesn't come to `onActivityResult` method. I have written my `onActivityResult` inside the `ActivityGroup` class.

This code for When User click on Camera button, it will open cameara & save it

```
       //Camera
    Button btnCamera =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             selectedImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+retailerCode+"-"+count+".jpg";
             imgName =retailerCode+"-"+count+".jpg";
             count++;
             File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
             Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
             Intent intent = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             b.putString("Activity", "RetailerOrderSActivity");
             b.putString("RetailerName", seletctedRetailer);
             b.putString("RetailerCode", retailerCode);
             intent.putExtras(b);
             intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
             startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
             onPhotoTaken();


        }
    });

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
         _taken = true;
         DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(CameraMainActivity.this);
         dbAdapter.openDataBase();
         boolean status = dbAdapter.saveImageInfo(retailerCode,strExecutive,strBusinessUnit,strTerritoryCode,imgName,visitNumber);
         if(status) {
          Toast.makeText(SalesActivityGroup.group.getApplicationContext(), "Image has been saved successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }else {
           Toast.makeText(SalesActivityGroup.group.getApplicationContext(), "Image has not been saved successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        dbAdapter.close();
        lstCaptures = getAllImage(imgDateVal.getText().toString());
        imageViewTable.removeAllViews();
        loadTableLayout();  
     }
```

This is code for ActivityGroup

```
      public class SalesActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {
          @Override
          protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       System.out.println("===REQUEST=====" +requestCode);
         System.out.println("==resultCode==" +resultCode); } }
```

Actually I need to call `onPhotoTaken`  from `onActivityResult`. According current my code if the user click cancel also, it saving information to DB. Image is not captured..

This is my app image :

[image]

This is button showing after capture image:

[image]
Please anybody sort out this issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6679665/940096) one.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following answer

Suppose I have a button **Select** & when the user clicks on the button , Camera screen will open.

```
btn_select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

          String fileName = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).append(
                                                        ".jpg").toString();
                  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                  values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                  mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                  values);
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, IShipdocsMobileConstants.CAMERA_ACTION);
                }
    });
```

After the user takes a photo & clicks on the Save/OK button (depends on the mobile device) , use the following code to fetch the data for the captured image.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == IShipdocsMobileConstants.CAMERA_ACTION) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                SelectedFileInfo selectedFileObj = null;
                ArrayList<SelectedFileInfo> cameraArrList = new ArrayList<SelectedFileInfo>();
                File fileObj = new File(capturedImageFilePath);
                String fileSize = String.valueOf(fileObj.length()); //File Size
                String fileName = Utils.getFileName(capturedImageFilePath); //File Name
                }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // handle the condition in which the user didn't save the image
                }
            } else {
                // handle the condition in which the request code was not CAMERA_ACTION , maybe send the user to the home/default screen
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is calling place I need to call  `getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);`  more details [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677466/stuck-with-getting-camera-pic-when-using-the-tab-activity/6679665#6679665)