# onActivityResult is never called in TabActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I know there are tons of the same questions, but still OnActivityResult is not being called.

This is my code

Activity A:

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(ActivityB.LINK, ad.getLink());
        i.putExtras(b);
        i.setClass(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        /*handling of result...*/
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Activity B :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ad_video);
    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    setResult(0);
    link = b.getString(LINK);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
     videoView.setVideoPath(_link);
     videoView.requestFocus();
     videoView.start();
     videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            setResult(0);
            ActivityB.this.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Whatever i do, `OnActivityResult` is never called.
Based on other questions

1. i put the setResult with values > 0 (0,99)
2. in android manifest there is no launchMode (I also tried to put
   launchMode to standard)

Thank you for any help

Comment: You sure you don't enter onActivityResult?
Also try not to use 0, shouldn't really be a problem, but I always avoid it in my codes. (as result/request code)

Comment: Yes I'm sure, i also tried setResult(99) same issue, my activity is an activity of tabActivity, if this can cause a problem

Comment: That matters, you don't finish the activity if you change between tabs AFAIK.

Comment: I didn't mean in setResult btw, I meant in requestcode

Comment: i changed it also in requestCode, activityA is a tab, but activityB is just an activity called inside it.

Comment: Do you know for sure if onCompletion() is being called?

Comment: You say you are calling from a tab activity. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677466/stuck-with-getting-camera-pic-when-using-the-tab-activity/6679665#6679665 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it,
The main issue was that i called the activtiy from within the tab host. I called it from the Activity that contains the tabs (the one that extends TabActivity) and it works.

So in brief, even though i'm using each tab as an activity,
 the one that should call the startActivityForResult is the main activity that extends TabActivity.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an intent to the result, this code works for me:

```
Intent in = new Intent(); 
setResult(101, in);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("ProfilePicPath", path);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the child activity, I used it on the child activity

```
getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, positive_request_code);
```