# Tab Activity not working for startActivityforResult()

Tags: android, tabactivity, onactivityresult

I have `NewMessage Activity` from which I am calling Tab Activity. Tab Activity Contains 3 Tab `Contacts|Group|Selected Contacts` I will select some contacts on contact tab and will redirect those contacts to `NewMessage` again. This thing is working fine without Tab Activity.

I refer some link

[stuck with getting camera pic when using the tab Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677466/stuck-with-getting-camera-pic-when-using-the-tab-activity/6679665#6679665)

[Android onActivityResult is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510280/android-onactivityresult-is-always-0)

[On Activity never calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739370/onactivityresult-is-never-called-in-tabactivity)

My Code:

> To Call The Tab Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,Tab.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT);
```

> Tab.Class

```
public class Tab extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);
        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec PhoneBook = tabHost.newTabSpec("PhoneBook");
        PhoneBook.setIndicator("PhoneBook");
        Intent PhoneBook = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
        PhoneBook.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec Groups = tabHost.newTabSpec("Groups");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        Groups.setIndicator("Groups");
        Intent Groups = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
        Groups.setContent(Groups);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec SelectedContacts = tabHost.newTabSpec("Selected Contacts");
        SelectedContacts.setIndicator("Selected Contacts");
        Intent SelectedContacts = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
        SelectedContacts.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(PhoneBook); // Adding PhoneBook
        tabHost.addTab(Groups); // Adding Group PhoneBook
        tabHost.addTab(SelectedContacts); // Adding SelectedContacts
    }
    //Menu Bar
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();       
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_list, menu);
          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);//This is actionBar Save Button
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();   
        //Save Button Click
        if (id == R.id.action_done) 
        {
            Log.d("Activity","Tab");

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> This is the Tab1.Class From which I need to pass on value ActionBar Save Button Click.

I have declare action_bar save button in Tab.Class because if I declare it in Tab1.class its not showing up.This is the code which I return back on save button Click

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();   
    //Save Button Click
    if (id == R.id.action_done) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ViewContactName.size(); i++)

        {
        if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
        {
          SelectedName.add(ViewContactName.get(i));
          SelectedPhoneNumber.add(ViewContatcPhnoeNo.get(i).replaceAll("[^0-9,+]", ""));
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ContactName",(ArrayList<String>) SelectedName);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ContactNumber", (ArrayList<String>) SelectedPhoneNumber);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

So what can be the solution? I used TabHost

Comment: You should provide the relevant code.

Comment: @Marcus : I have put all the code which is concerned with my issue now