# startActivityForResult from ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am using ActivityGroup. I use the following code from ActivityGroup in order to replace view and launch a new activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SummaryCostScreen.this,PermissionsScreen.class);
replaceContentView("activity1",i);

public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, 
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
}
```

The problem with the above code is that, I need to have **startActivityForResult** in place of **startActivity**, since I need to update the UI of launcher activity when coming back from the launched activity.

**getLocalActivityManager()** does not have  startActivityForResult. How should I address this situation, such that, I am able to update UI from onActivityResult?

Any help is much appreciated.

**PS**: *I cannot change the replaceContentView approach for launching new screen, since that has been used at numerous other places and this is the only scenario in which I need to call startActivityForResult*

Comment: You can use `onResume()` to update UI of `SummerCostScreen`

Comment: Whatever I had in onactivityresult, when I paste it it in onResume, it does not update the UI. So, it is not working the way you suggested.

Comment: Place a debugger and check, is it entering to the `onResume` or not.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It worked. One more question, is this the efficient method, since, I have to maintain a static bolean variable in called activity and track and update its status in caller activity?

Comment: Using intent extra to send its status and update it based on that..ok I'll post the same as answer

Comment: when coming back from second activity, how does intent extra work? can you please post that as well?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6679665/593709) may be of some help.

Comment: @user1400538 StartActivityForResult and then setResult in the second Activity and then finish it. And in onResume() get their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments as answer,
Try using  `onResume()` to update UI of `SummerCostScreen`