# In ActivityGroup onActivityResult is not working?

Tags: android, android-contacts, activitygroup

I am opening contact list in activity group contact list is opening after selecting contact onActivityResult is not working.if any one have idea please help me thanks in advance.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST)   {

}
}
```

Comment: why do you use `getParent().startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: i am calling contact list in activity group

Comment: In this case, you should handle data `onActivityResult` in your activity group.

Comment: but onActivityResult is not working

Comment: Have a look at [**stuck with getting camera pic when using the tab Activity**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6679665/593709), its the kind of same issue which are you facing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got my answer  by overing onActivityResult in ParentActivity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ChildActivityName activity = (ChildActivityName)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
            System.out.println("onActivity..");
            activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }
```

in child Activity

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: @Sai..Hello Sai.... Here what's the Request Code? I know that, but how u can get it from other activity?

Comment: Request code is Activity.RESULT_OK or Activity.RESULT_CANCEl it will come by default,u r opening free defined app like contacts etc... or if u opening your own  activity u need to call   getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);