# Android wait for another activity result - it didn't work

Tags: android

How to wait to another activity result in android. 
I have written the following code but after the activity finishes, it always goes to onCreate() method.

**I have tab activity.From one tab activity , i called another activity, that is popup window......After finished popup window It should go back to previous activity**

```
   @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    keyword = o.toString();
    positions = position;

    if(position != 0 ){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SalesRouteDevitionActivity.class);
        int postion = position;
        String aString = Integer.toString(postion);
        bundle.putString("positon", aString);
        showContent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivityForResult(showContent,0);
    }else{

        Intent intent = new Intent(SalesRouteActivity.this, ListRetailerActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("RouteName", keyword);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        View view = SalesActivityGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();  
        SalesActivityGroup.group.replaceView(view);
    }
}


   @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

       Log.w("onActivityResult" ," --requestCode ---" + requestCode + " -- resultCode -- " + resultCode + " -- data --" + data);
      if(resultCode==0){
          Toast.makeText(this, "Reason has been successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
              Toast.makeText(this, "Reason has been successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         else
              Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  }
```

and SalesRouteDevitionActivity.class

```
    public class SalesRouteDevitionActivity extends Activity {
private String array_spinner[];
String param1 = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.route_diviation_popup);
    array_spinner=new String[2];
    array_spinner[0]="Rain";
    array_spinner[1]="Floods";

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {


             Intent mIntent = new Intent();
             setResult(RESULT_OK);
             finish();



         }
     });

}

}
```

This is my Tab Activity.I am using ActivityGroup

```
  public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
int selectedTab;
TabHost tabHost ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabview);

    TabHost t = getTabHost();
    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
    /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Sales").setContent(new Intent(this,SalesActivityGroup.class));
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Admin").setContent(new Intent(this,SettingActivityGroup.class));
    thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Setting").setContent(new Intent(this,SettingActivityGroup.class));


    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    tabHost.setMinimumHeight(25);
}

public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
        selectedTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

}
```

This is SalesActivityGroup.java

```
 public class SalesActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

public static SalesActivityGroup group;
private ArrayList<View> history;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
    group = this;

    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Sales",
            new Intent(this, SalesRouteActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();

    replaceView(view);

}

public void replaceView(View v) {
    history.add(v);
    setContentView(v);

}

public void back() {
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        history.remove(history.size() - 1);
        if (history.size() > 0) {
            setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SalesActivityGroup.group.back();
    return;
}
```

}

I know this is the way we should do, but really i dont know why its not working my part....

I didn't go to onActivityResult() method & it didnt print `Log`  also

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268178/startactivityforresult-from-activitygroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using tab ActivityGroup then should use like this:

Calling activity:

```
 Intent showContent = new Intent(botton.getContext(),RetailerOrderEActivity.class);
 getParent().startActivityForResult(showContent, 2);
```

consider `getParent()`, If it is Tab activityGroup then call like that.

and child Activity:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
```

after finish this will go to ActivityGroup class:

there you want to call like this:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode ==1){
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        String roteCode = bundle.getString("RouteCode");
        Intent intent = new Intent(SalesActivityGroup.this,ListRetailerActivity.class);
        bundle.putString("RouteCode", roteCode);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        View view = SalesActivityGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("",intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
        SalesActivityGroup.group.replaceView(view);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove `startActivity(showContent);` from SalesRouteDevitionActivity.class
Edit:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: No.I have tried this also.I didnt go onActivityResult() method

Comment: I commented that part.Even though not going that place

Comment: Please change this `if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)` to   `if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)`

Comment: Also change ` if(resultCode==0)` to ` if(requestCode==0)`

Comment: @NagkeeranPiraba let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2263/discussion-between-sandy-and-nagkeeran-piraba)

Answer (score 3):

There is no console in  Android. So `System.out.println` won't work. For debug purposes, you can use the `LogCat`. [Here's how to use LogCat](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#logging)

Comment: @sparkymat `System.out.println` are visible in Log.i

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to call

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

when you are handling ActivityResult.

Replace your System.out.println with Log.i

Comment: Remove super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); from the method

Comment: I commented that part.Even though not going that place

Comment: do you see the first line with Log.w?

Comment: No.I didnt see Log out put.I think Its go to oncreate() method.

Comment: Are you using intent for activities within each tab?

Comment: YEs.My case I am set up in Androidamnifest  like this ` <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name=".SalesRouteDevitionActivity"
                  android:label="Sales Route Diviation">
        </activity>` Then call like above code

Comment: Tab Activities are tricky can you put onActivityResult in your MainActivity and see if that is the activity getting the result?

Answer (score 3):

replace this

```
if(resultCode==0)
```

with this

```
if(requestCode==0)
```