# OnActivityResult on Android when using GroupActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [startActivityForResult from ActivityGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268178/startactivityforresult-from-activitygroup)

Is there a way to use OnActivityresult when u are using GroupActivity?

Comment: This has been flagged as a duplicate of 4268178. Please refrain from posting duplicate questions.  If in doubt read [ask]