# ActivityGroup implementation

Tags: android, activitygroup

I have implemented `ActivityGroup` inside the Tabs. I am going from Activity `A` to Activity `B`. In Activity `B` I launch a camera and `B's` `onActivityResult()` is not called. So I implemented `onActivityResult()` in `ActivityGroup` and it called.

How to go to `onActivityResult()` of my Activity `B` from where I started the camera from `ActivityGroup's` `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268178/startactivityforresult-from-activitygroup) link.

Comment: i Checked that link ..abut not able to move forward after 2nd point

Comment: go [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/522/android-for-life) and ask to Dharmendra.

Comment: Since u r using ActivityGroup u might have hold of your activity history which you can make use of somehow?