# Prevent Re Loading an Activity while returning from Camera App

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, android-orientation

I am creating an app which uses the camera app to take pictures. Once I return from the camera app the entire view gets recreated. To stop this I have added

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in the Manifest file for the specified activities. But this is still happening.

To be more precise of my issue, I am using Activity Group with TabHost. After a picture is taken using the camera I am redirecting the user to a different screen. But this is not working as the entire view is reloaded. Instead the user is taken back to the first screen in activity group.

I dont want this to happen. Is it posible to set orientation fro camera! How can I do this properly?

For those interested I am adding the code which I use to start camera

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/myimage.jpg"));
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
this.getParent().startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

Thanks

Comment: you should use `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the code I am using FYI.

Comment: Why are you using this.getParent() simply use this.startActivityForResult and define the method onActivityResult.

Comment: I am using an Activty group. startActivityForResult wont give a callback to a view inside the group but only to the parent of that view. Thats why I am using it. This post will explain it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268178/startactivityforresult-from-activitygroup

Comment: @Zach-Did you find the solution to this ?